# Time-efficient algorithm to find the largest area in a grid with constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph

In a 2D grid, we start from the origin (0, 0) and then we can move by one cell at the time with either (x+1, x-1, y+1, y-1).
I have to find the largest area with this constraint: for any point in the area, the sum of the digits of abs(x) plus the sum of the digits of abs(y) should be at most 23.

For example, the point (59,75) isn't valid because 5 + 9 + 7 + 5 = 26.
The point (-51, -7) is valid because 5 + 1 + 7 = 13, which is less than 23.

What could be a way to solve this with great time-complexity ?

Comment: So what are **YOUR** thoughts so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this picture. It shows as white those points with digits sum < 23 in the first quadrant reachable from coordinate origin (edit: needed <=23).

Seems it is not hard to make breadth-first search like flood-fill with special border condition `sumdigit <=23` (coordinate limit is 699) and count them all.

White filling spreads from origin until border value is met. This process resembles water flooding with level 23. Black islands stay in white sea and solid black border limits it. Count of white pixels is area of continuous region around origin.
.

Moreover, it is possible to determine count of white points in every 100x100 square depending on its coordinates and get mathematical formula.

[image]

Scaled fragment:

[image]

Primitive implementation in Delphi (there are effective non-recursive Floodfill implementations) gives white pixel count 592597

```
var
  mark: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;

function digitsum(x, y: integer): integer;
begin
  if mark.ContainsKey((x + 1000) * 2000 + y + 1000) then
    Exit(9999);
  Result := 0;
  x := abs(x);
  y := abs(y);
  while y > 0 do begin
    Result := Result + y mod 10;
    y := y div 10;
  end;
  while x > 0 do begin
    Result := Result + x mod 10;
    x := x div 10;
  end;
end;

function flood(x, y: integer): integer;
begin
  if digitsum(x,y) > 23 then
    Exit(0);
  Result := 1;
  mark.Add((x + 1000) * 2000 + y + 1000, 0);
  Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := clWhite;
  Inc(Result, flood(x + 1, y));
  Inc(Result, flood(x - 1, y));
  Inc(Result, flood(x, y - 1));
  Inc(Result, flood(x, y + 1));
end;

begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  mark:= TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create;
  Caption := flood(0, 0).ToString;
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what it's implied by "the greatest area", if the output should be 
the coordinates of the largest area or its number of cells. I found some stuff on DFS search but I'll take a look on BFS too.

Comment: Result will be the same for DFS and BFS. I think that "the greatest area" means overall count of white points in all four quadrants (we can calculate for one quadrant including y=0 but excluding x=0, then multiply by 4 (and add 1 for point 0,0))

Comment: Another question came across my mind: with DFS for example, we could be expanding in each direction proportionally, but how can I make sure that it's the largest area ?

Comment: There is only one **connected** area available from coordinate origin. There are many  pieces with digitsum < 23, but they are separated from central one.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, for me, on a specific node, we could go up/right/down/left, which leaves 4 options ?

Comment: We can go only if digit sum <= 23. At least this is my understanding of the problem. If we stay at (38,39), we cannot go to (39,39) but can go to (38,40), (38,38), (37,39)

Comment: I agree with that, so why did you say "There is only one connected area available from coordinate origin''

Comment: Because.. there is only one. I painted it white.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219658/discussion-between-theo-lavaux-and-mbo).